# Naming Problem in Microservice System Design

Tags: architecture, microservices, grpc, naming

Thanks for coming to this unusual question. So I was designing a system architecture with microservices architecture. I divided the system into multiple services. Such as Auth, Interaction, etc.

Are they services or microservices or APIs? Obviously, they are accessed by REST API. What should I call them? **Auth API** or **Auth Service**?

Also, they talk to each other with gRPC which requires defining the RPCs in a service. What should I call that? Such as **AuthDataTransferService** or **AuthDataTransferAPI**??

I am quite a beginner in this field, so sorry in advance for any mistakes in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name micro**services** suggests you divide your application into small, independent services. So, calling your highest level components as services is absolutely a good approach.

Calling them XYZ*API* would prevent you from future extensions. Even though your service expose its functionalities today as a REST/gRPC API, it does not mean you don't need to provide a web/mobile UI as well for your future consumers.

---

Please also note that `Auth` abbreviation is ambiguous. Did you mean **Authentication** or **Authorization**? Former is usually abbreviated as **AuthC**,  whereas latter as **AuthZ**.

Comment: I meant Authentication... Thanks for the info. But what should the application code's repo be named?

Comment: @MohammadArik You should simply use XYZService or prefix the code repository with a company name, like AckeCorp.AuthenticationService